# Properly free memory alloc'd with enif_resource_alloc

Tags: c, erlang, alloc

I have written an Erlang C NIF that returns a pointer to a structure after calling new and for now just increments a variable on insert.  I am wondering how to properly destroy the original resource, or at least mark it for GC.  I am having no luck.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "erl_nif.h"


typedef struct level {
    float a;
    float b;
} LVL;

// data array with key being the price
typedef struct book {
    int array_size; // # of TTL indices
    int len; // # of Occupied indices (inc. val) from bestPriceIndex
    int max_len; 

    LVL lvl_data[];

} Book;


static ErlNifResourceType *MEM_RESOURCE;


    static int
on_load(ErlNifEnv *env, void **priv_data, ERL_NIF_TERM load_info)
{
    ErlNifResourceFlags flags = (ErlNifResourceFlags)(ERL_NIF_RT_CREATE);

    if ( (MEM_RESOURCE = enif_open_resource_type(env, 
            NULL,
            "mem_resource", 
            NULL, //dtor
            flags, 
            NULL)) == NULL)
        return -1;

    return 0;
}


    static ERL_NIF_TERM 
new( ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[] ) 
{   
    int max_len = 50;

    int mem_size = sizeof(Book) + max_len * sizeof(LVL);
    Book *q = enif_alloc_resource(MEM_RESOURCE, mem_size );
        if( q == NULL ) return enif_make_string(env, "could not alloc", ERL_NIF_LATIN1);

    q->lvl_data[0].a = 7.0;     

    ERL_NIF_TERM term = enif_make_resource(env, q);

    enif_release_resource(q);

    return term;
};


    static ERL_NIF_TERM 
insert( ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[] ) 
{
    Book *p;
    if (!enif_get_resource(env, argv[0], MEM_RESOURCE, (void **)&p)) 
       return enif_make_badarg(env); 

    float x = ++p->lvl_data[0].a;

    return enif_make_string(env, "okk", ERL_NIF_LATIN1);
};


static ErlNifFunc nif_funcs[] = 
{ 
    {"new", 0, new},
    {"insert", 1, insert}
};

ERL_NIF_INIT( test, nif_funcs, on_load, NULL, NULL, NULL )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are no terms holding the resource, the resource will be collected *automatically* by GC.

Comment: I do not understand when or who holds the last resource.  I already use  enif_release_resource(q); just before returning from the new function.  What else must I do?

Comment: @user417896: If you returned the resource with enif_make_resource, then absolutely nothing. Erlang uses reference counting on terms to determine when there are no more copies of the term floating around. When this is the case it is automatically garbage collected and your destructor is invoked.

Comment: This only applies to terms returned with enif_make_resource; it's entirely possible to allocate a resource object and explicitly release it with enif_release_resource, but once you call enif_make_resource it is memory-managed. You can also explicitly release it if only one process has a reference to the term and that process invokes a nif which calls enif_release_resource. Suffice it to say that enif_release_resource decrements the reference counter, whereas enif_make_resource increments it.

Comment: @Soup d'Campbells Thanks for that info, but to clarify, is the enif_release_resource immediately following the enif_make_resource in the function new incorrect?

Comment: No, in fact it's necessary (it can be delayed, but you must eventually release it). In your code: enif_alloc_resource creates a memory managed resource with a reference count of one. enif_make_resouce makes a valid erlang term from the resource *and* increments the reference counter, so it has a count of two after that. enif_release_resource decrements it again, leaving `term` as the only valid reference. It's allocated to the calling process' env, so when that process dies and is garbage collected the final reference is removed, the destructor is revoked, and the memory is freed.

Comment: Sharing `term` between processes via message passing will increment the reference counter, prolonging the life of the resource, etc.. Long and short of it is you need to release the value returned by enif_alloc_resource (or enif_keep_resource) at least once during the lifetime of your program.

Comment: Terms are stored inside an environment ErlNifEnv. While resources are reference counted, most of other terms are not. You can just _copy_ a term from one env to another. When you don't need an environment, you delete it and all terms inside of it will gone. When VM runs GC, it creates a new environment, copies alive terms to it and deletes the old environment.